# Using imported libraries in Qt

Tags: qt

I have imported a library using

```
LIBS += -Lhome/Integration/HelloSumit/DefaultComponent/DefaultConfig -aDefaultComponentA
```

in my Qt project. Now I want to use that in my .cpp file. How do I do that? Do I need to create an object of the library?

Comment: What kind of library is it? What do you already have (only the library or also headers)?

Comment: its a simple library. I have the libraries as well as the headers with me. By i dont know how to incuklde them in my oproject. I tried inluding the header files by HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \ home/Integration/HelloSumit/DefaultComponent/DefaultConfig/MainDefaultComponent.h but still i m nt able to access the function in my cpp file..Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the question comments, adding the external library header in .pro file `HEADERS` section is not the way to go. (It signals qmake to run the header through the meta-object compiler.) Instead add

```
INCLUDEPATH += home/Integration/HelloSumit/DefaultComponent/DefaultConfig
```

to your .pro file and

```
#include <MainDefaultComponent.h>
```

in your .cpp file to access the declarations therein.

Comment: I tried adding an Include Path and defining the path to look for the header files. But when I compile the project I get an error which says. error: MainDefaultComponent.h: No such file or directory.:(

Comment: Should there be a / in front of "home/Integration..."?